# R 'plspm' error: path_matrix must be a lower triangular matrix (partial least squares path modeling/sem)

Tags: r, matrix, structural-equation-model

I am attempting to evaluate an SEM using the 'plspm' function in the R package of the same name. I have two competing models:

Model 1:

```
A<-c(0,0,0)
B<-c(1,0,0)
C<-c(0,1,0)
sat_path=rbind(A,B,C)
innerplot(sat_path)
```

versus

Model 2:

```
A<-c(0,1,0)
B<-c(0,0,0)
C<-c(0,1,0)
sat_path=rbind(A,B,C)
innerplot(sat_path)
```

Thus, the difference lies only in the direction of the arrow between A and B.

When I run the code (see below), the first model (Model 1) returns an answer, while the second model (Model 2) returns the following error:

> Error in check_path(path_matrix) : 'path_matrix' must be a lower triangular matrix

My question: WHYYYYYY???! I do not see any logic in how the first matrix can be in the correct format, while the second cannot. Am I confused about what constitutes a "lower triangular matrix"? Below are the full codes and some data to run it yourself. Thanks in advance!

```
#Some play data:
Xdat<-rep(c(1,1,0,0,1),300)
XX<-matrix(Xdat,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(XX)<-c("A","B","C")
XX<-as.data.frame(XX)
attach(XX)

### Model 1: ####
pf<-c(0,0,0)
pm<-c(1,0,0)
po<-c(0,1,0)
sat_path=rbind(pf,pm,po)

# plot diagram of path matrix
innerplot(sat_path)

# blocks of outer model
sat_blocks = list(which(names(XX)=="A"), which(names(XX)=="B"), which(names(XX)=="C"))

# vector of modes (reflective indicators)
sat_mod = rep("A", 3)

# apply plspm
satpls = plspm(XX, sat_path, sat_blocks, modes = sat_mod,
               scaled = FALSE)

# plot diagram of the inner model
innerplot(satpls)

### Model 2: ####
A<-c(0,1,0)
B<-c(0,0,0)
C<-c(0,1,0)
sat_path=rbind(pf,pm,po)

# plot diagram of path matrix
innerplot(sat_path)

# blocks of outer model
sat_blocks = list(which(names(XX)=="A"), which(names(XX)=="B"), which(names(XX)=="C"))

# vector of modes (reflective indicators)
sat_mod = rep("A", 3)

# apply plspm
satpls = plspm(XX, sat_path, sat_blocks, modes = sat_mod,
               scaled = FALSE)
# this ends in an error (or should...!)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out why this is a problem. Sat with the same problem, and couldnt figure out how to solve it.

I looked up Triangular matrix on wiki, and found out that a Triangular matrix is a matrix where over the diagonal there are 0's. That means that to be able to create model 2, you just have to chance the order in which to specify the factors.

Model 2

```
A<-c(0,1,0)
B<-c(0,0,0)
C<-c(0,1,0)
sat_path=rbing(A,B,C)
```

Instead do this: 
Model 2:

```
B<-c(0,0,0)
A<-c(1,0,0)
C<-c(1,0,0)
sat_path=rbing(B,A,C)
```

Same model, but not triangular matrix.

Hope you figure it out ;)

Comment: oh wow! you know what, I am so used to looking at pairwise interaction matrices below the diagonal that I only considered the diagonal running top left to bottom right! I, too, had looked to the wikis to figure it out and was so confused as to why model 2 did not fit the bill - this is why! Thanks for figuring it out and posting your response. Nice workaround, too!